# How to get the results of a mean and standard deviation to the same data frame by creating extra columns (mean and standard deviation) in R

Tags: r

how to get the results of a mean  and standard deviation to the same data frame by creating extra columns (mean and standard deviation) in R

**DATA:

```
     category sex day    flag    value
1        FC   M   -1          a     27.5
2        FC   M   -1          a     25.2
3        FC   M   -1          a     22.0
4        FC   M   -1          a     24.3
5        FC   M   -1          a     24.0
6        FC   M   -1          a     29.3
7        FC   M   -1          a     23.4
8        FC   M   -1          a     29.3
9        FC   M   -1          a     23.4
10       FC   M   -1          a     29.3
11       FC   M   -1          a     28.3
12       FC   M   -1          a     30.2
13       FC   M   -1          a     30.2
```

**code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(doBy)
library(tidyverse)
data <- read.csv("users/category.csv")
print(data)


new_table <- select(data, category, sex, day, flag,value)
filtered<-filter(new_table, sex=="M", category=="FC", flag=="a", day==-1)
filtered
```

**output should be:**

```
     category sex day      flag    value    mean    Standard deviation
1        FC   M   -1          a     27.5    27.5       2.8   
2        FC   M   -1          a     25.2
3        FC   M   -1          a     22.0
4        FC   M   -1          a     24.3
5        FC   M   -1          a     24.0
6        FC   M   -1          a     29.3
7        FC   M   -1          a     23.4
8        FC   M   -1          a     29.3
9        FC   M   -1          a     23.4
10       FC   M   -1          a     29.3
11       FC   M   -1          a     28.3
12       FC   M   -1          a     30.2
13       FC   M   -1          a     30.2
```

Comment: You could calculate those statistics using `aggregate` and then merge (left join) to your existing dataset. But, this will fill in all rows, repeating the values when necessary.

Comment: How do you get a mean and standard deviation with those values given the posted data? The values I found were different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `dplyr` and add it to your `filter` pipe chain, but values will be repeated:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(value),
         `Standard deviation` = sd(value))
```

Or in base `R` after filtering:

```
df$mean <- mean(df$value)
df$`Standard deviation` <- sd(df$value)
```

**Output**

```
   category sex day flag value     mean Standard devation
1        FC   M  -1    a  27.5 26.64615          2.987646
2        FC   M  -1    a  25.2 26.64615          2.987646
3        FC   M  -1    a  22.0 26.64615          2.987646
4        FC   M  -1    a  24.3 26.64615          2.987646
5        FC   M  -1    a  24.0 26.64615          2.987646
6        FC   M  -1    a  29.3 26.64615          2.987646
7        FC   M  -1    a  23.4 26.64615          2.987646
8        FC   M  -1    a  29.3 26.64615          2.987646
9        FC   M  -1    a  23.4 26.64615          2.987646
10       FC   M  -1    a  29.3 26.64615          2.987646
11       FC   M  -1    a  28.3 26.64615          2.987646
12       FC   M  -1    a  30.2 26.64615          2.987646
13       FC   M  -1    a  30.2 26.64615          2.987646
```

If you need to add values to those columns for groups of `category`, `sex`, `flag`, etc. then you can use `dplyr::group_by` on those variables *before* the `mutate` function.